# Ошибка установки wss WebSocket соединения

Tags: php, сокет, websocket, ssl

Упрощенный код сервера:

```
$ip="127.0.0.1";             
$port="8099"; 
$pem_passphrase = "wdwedwdw";
$pem_file = "filename.pem";   

$pem_dn = array(
 "countryName" => "UK",
 "stateOrProvinceName" => "Herts",  
 "localityName" => "St. Albans",    
 "organizationName" => "Your Company", 
 "organizationalUnitName" => "Your Department",
 "commonName" => "Your full hostname",
 "emailAddress" => "email@example.com"
);

echo "Creating SSL Cert\n";
createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn);
echo "Listening to {$ip}:{$port} for connections\n";
$socket = setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port);
if (!$socket) {die("$errstr ($errno)\n");}

function setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port) {
 $context = stream_context_create();
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem_file);  // Our SSL Cert in PEM format
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pem_passphrase); // Private key Password
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
 $socket = stream_socket_server("ssl://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context); 
 return $socket;
}

function createSSLCert($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $pem_dn) {
 $privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
 $cert    = openssl_csr_new($pem_dn, $privkey);
 $cert    = openssl_csr_sign($cert, null, $privkey, 365);
 $pem = array();
 openssl_x509_export($cert, $pem[0]);
 openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $pem[1], $pem_passphrase);
 $pem = implode($pem);
 file_put_contents($pem_file, $pem);
 chmod($pem_file, 0600);
}

if (!$socket) {die("$errstr ($errno)\n");}
echo "--демон чат сервера стартовал\n";
$connects = array();

while (true) {
    //формируем массив прослушиваемых сокетов:
    $read = $connects;
    $read []= $socket;
    $write = $except = null;
    if (!stream_select($read, $write, $except, null)) {break;}
    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
    $connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1);
    if ($connect==true){
        $info = handshakeSocket($connect);
        if ($info==true){
            $connects[] = $connect;//добавляем его в список необходимых для обработки
            onOpen($connect, $info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий            
        };
    };

        unset($read[ array_search($socket, $read) ]);
    }
    foreach($read as $connect) {//обрабатываем все соединения
        $data = fread($connect, 100000);
        if (!$data) { //соединение было закрыто 
            fclose($connect);
            unset($connects[ array_search($connect, $connects) ]);
            onClose($connect);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
            continue;
        }
        onMessage($connect, $data,$info);//вызываем пользовательский сценарий
    }
}
fclose($server);
```

Сервер запускается нормально, однако из браузера, если в консоли запустить:

```
zz=new WebSocket("wss://127.0.0.1:8099")
```

Выходит ошибка: WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8099/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_SERVER_CERT_BAD_FORMAT

Comment: так у вас ssl неправильный на сервере. Может вообще не установлен. Смотрите логи php на сервере для дебага.

Comment: В логах (ну которые выплевывает скрипт в терминал), ничего нет. Open SSL установлен. Файл сертификата формируется.

Comment: в логах интерпритатора php-cli или fpm

Comment: Скрипт запускается php <скрипт.php> в терминале. Все ошибки если есть должны валится в терминал. Их нет. OS: Ubuntu 15.4

Comment: После того как в файрефоксе добавил узел в исключения, то $connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1); стал выдавать ошибку: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate

Comment: Пробовал подпехивать вместо самоподписного сертификата, "подтвержденный" сертификат, выданый COMONDO - тоже самое..